# Illegal start of expression error in Java

Tags: java

Here's the code I'm having an issue with:

```
    class Drunk
{
        final int N = 5;
        int steps = 0;
        int corner = 5;

        public static int drunkWalk()
        {

                System.out.println("Here we go again... time for a walk!");

                do
                {
                        int lOrR = Math.Random();
                        if (lOrR < 0.5)
                        {
                                corner++;
                        }
                        if (lOrR > 0.5)
                        {
                                corner--;
                        }
                        steps++;
                } while (corner != 0 && corner != 10);

                if (corner = 0)
                {
                        System.out.println("Took " + steps +", and");
                        System.out.println("Landed at HOME");
                        System.out.println("");
                }
                if (corner = 10)
                {
                        System.out.println("Took " + steps +", and");
                        System.out.println("Landed at JAIL");
                        System.out.println("");
                }

                return steps;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
                }
                        drunkWalk();
                }

                System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
        }
}
```

Here are errors Java complains:

```
Drunk.java:45: error: illegal start of expression
        }
        ^
Drunk.java:49: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                          ^
Drunk.java:49: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                           ^
Drunk.java:49: error: ')' expected
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                                                       ^
Drunk.java:49: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                                                         ^
Drunk.java:49: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                                                                ^
Drunk.java:49: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                                                                    ^
Drunk.java:49: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                                                                     ^
Drunk.java:49: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                                                                      ^
Drunk.java:49: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println("Average # of steps equals " + (steps / N));
                                                                       ^
10 errors
```

I checked my code many times, but couldn't find what is causing the issue and how to fix it. Could anybody help me?

Comment: You put a closing brace `{` instead of an opening brace `}` after the `for`. Quick, [delete] the question :-)

Comment: Inside your `if`-statements: write `==` instead of just `=`

Comment: Soo... Have you tried to read what was stated in the first two lines of the error message, maybe have a look at line 45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multipe errors :

1.

Assignment (=) instead of comparison (==) in your if statements.

2.

Non static members, which are later accessed from static methods :

```
    final int N = 5;
    int steps = 0;
    int corner = 5;
```

3.

Wrong method name, and wrong return type :

```
int lOrR = Math.Random();
```

Should be

```
double lOrR = Math.random();
```

4.

Closing brackets instead of opening brackets :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
}
    drunkWalk();
}
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{
    drunkWalk();
}
```

Comment: 1, 3, 4 solved. For 2, I add "static" at beginning. Does that work?

Comment: And still have errors below(can't type in all of them, but they are of same kind): Drunk.java:44: error: ';' expected
for (int i == 1; i <= N; i++)
            ^                                  Drunk.java:44: error: illegal start of expression
  for (int i == 1; i <= N; i++)
             ^
Drunk.java:44: error: ';' expected
  for (int i == 1; i <= N; i++)
               ^
Drunk.java:44: error: illegal start of expression
  for (int i == 1; i <= N; i++)
                 ^
Drunk.java:44: error: ')' expected
  for (int i == 1; i <= N; i++)
                  ^

Comment: @user3856086 Did you fix error #4 (} to {)?

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in the following part:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
}
    drunkWalk();
}
```

The first brace is a `}`, where it should be a `{`. Example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{
    drunkWalk();
}
```

With your current code the Java VM thinks you're closing a scope twice, instead you should be opening one.

Comment: This is really helpful, but still, the code has errors. Please check my comment to another answer.